# Ctrl + W works as if Ctrl + V... but only once

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, keymap

I'm having a strange issue with Ctrl + W on Windows 10.

When I press Ctrl + W, it pastes my clipboard... the first time. But if I continue to hold Ctrl, and press W again, it prints "w".

It's as if Windows "forgets" that Ctrl is being held - if I press any key, it acts as its normal key, without a Ctrl modifier.

Here's an example:

I open NotePad. My clipboard contains "Hello".

- I press W

  > File reads "w"
- I hold Ctrl
- I press W

  > File reads "wHello"
- I press W

  > File reads "wHellow"
- I press A

  > File reads "wHellowa"
- I release Ctrl

The behaviour is the same on all programs I've tested.

I've previously edited the registry keymap, but since reverted it. `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` contains only `(Default)`

I'm trying to map Ctrl + W to close tabs in Android Studio, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out TenClips Clipboard Manager overrides Ctrl + W by default

I got my Ctrl + W back by:

- Opening TenClips settings
- Removing the shortcut for "Paste purified text", which was set to Ctrl + W by default

Apparently these settings will be reset on reboot unless you pay for TenClips... so I am now using [CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ)